# Update with WHERE clause JOIN another table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have the following table:

**HABIT**

```
ID INT PRIMARY KEY

NUMBER INT FOREIGN KEY

DATE DATE

DONE BOOL
```

---

**HABIT_DESCRIPTION**

```
NUMBER INT PRIMARY KEY

NAME VARCHAR

DESCRIPTION VARCHAR
```

I want to make an update on specific row in HABIT where name of HABIT_DESCRIPTION is <some_string>

I tried this:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(HABIT_COL_DONE, true);
    String whereclause = HABIT_DESCRIPTION_NAME+ "='water'";
    return db.update("HABIT",cv,whereclause,null);
```

Comment: What is the relation of HABIT and HABIT_DESCRIPTION?

Comment: It is NUMBER, I edited the question to show PK and FK

Comment: You really want [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) columns, not `INT PRIMARY KEY`, btw.

Comment: Using `VARCHAR`, `BOOL`, etc. suggests you should also read over https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **SQLite** does not support joins in the `UPDATE` statement, you can use `EXISTS`:

```
String whereclause = 
    "EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM HABIT_DESCRIPTION WHERE NUMBER = HABIT.NUMBER AND DESCRIPTION = ?)";
String param = "water";
return db.update("HABIT", cv, whereclause, new String[] {param});
```